# How do I do math based on contents of .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have been given a text file that is 16 numbers aligned 4x4. I am tasked with separating each row and column into respective regions and quarters then finding out the total for region 1-4, quarter 1-4, and the total of every data entry.

```py
with open("data.txt",'r') as data_file:
for line in data_file:
    data = line.split()
    data = list(data)
    q1 = data[0]
    q2 = data[1]
    q3 = data[2]
    q4 = data[3]
    iq1 = int(q1)
    sq1 = sum(iq1)
    print(sq1)
```

Is what I have tried so far. I get an error that the int is not iterable. How do I convert this .txt file into data that I can apply math to? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `with open("data.txt",'r') as data_file: data = [ list(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in data_file]`  should put all your numbers in a list of list. Do your math on that

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` function takes an iterable object as input.

Firstly you can convert your string data to int list as below:

```py
# string list to int list
my_values = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), data[:4]))

# sum of int list
sum_of_my_values = sum(my_values)
```

Comment: Well, `lambda x: int(x)` is a complicated way of saying.... `int`. Also you didn't really need to create a list (or tuple in your case). You can pass the `map` directly to `sum`: `sum(map(int, data))`

Comment: You are right! but I have just written it explicitly.

Comment: *explicitly* does not always mean *simplicity* and most times the latter is more important...